# How to get this accessToken?

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyzK1.png)

```
const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        return fetch(url+loginApi,{
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            body:JSON.stringify({
                email: agent.email,
                password:agent.password
            })
        })
        .then((result)=>{
            console.log(result)
        })
    }
```

This is my code. I am getting Status OK code but how to access the accessToken

Comment: use result.json() and after that log the result

Comment: Add more context to your question you are showing making post request only for logging in I assume. Show code where your handling this interaction of logging in

Answer (score 1):

With the JavaScript `fetch` function you need to parse the response before you can use it like this

```
const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    return fetch(url+loginApi,{
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        body:JSON.stringify({
            email: agent.email,
            password:agent.password
        })
    })

    //*** add the following line ***//

    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((result)=>{
        console.log(result)
        //*** or for the token ***//
        console.log(result.accessToken)
    })
}
```

Comment: tried this.but it is giving me the status:OK output not the accessToken